# NSTextField - Allow editing only with force-touch, Cocoa

Tags: swift, macos, cocoa, nstextfield, force-touch

I am developing a OSX app with Force touch support.

As default, if you set an NSTextField's behaviour editable, user can click two times or use force touch to start editing.

I want to allow user start editing only with Force touch. How can I handle this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Subclass NSTextField and override `pressureChange(with:)`.
Then, check `event.stage` for the level of the pressure (or `event.pressure` for the accurate value). If event.stage is `2`, it is the force touch.

```
@available(macOS 10.10.3, *)
override func pressureChange(with event: NSEvent) {

    if event.stage == 2, !self.isEditable {
        self.isEditable = true
        self.selectText(self)
    }
}
```